# Error al crear un trigger con MySql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer un trigger con MySql, el problema es que siempre he trabajado con Sql-Server y ahora estoy teniendo algunas complicaciones. Del siguiente código qué es lo que tengo mal? :

```
USE `test_db`;
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON purchases FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @usuario varchar(30), @accion varchar(6), @customer varchar(8)
    SET @usuario = (SELECT Cus_User FROM INSERTED)
    SET @accion = 'creado';
    SET @customer = (SELECT Cus_Id FROM INSERTED)
    INSERT INTO his_cus (HCu_Action, HCu_User, HCu_Cus_Id) VALUES(@accion,@usuario,@customer)
END;
$$
```

Al intentar crearlo (con phpMyAdmin) sale el siguiente error: `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '@usuario varchar(30), @accion varchar(6), @customer varchar(8)SET @usuario' en la linea 5`

Lo que hace el trigger por si sirve de ayuda es obtener los datos del `INSERT` e insertarlos en otra tabla a modo de historial de acciones de los usuarios

Comment: No necesitas declarar las variables de usuario (las que empiezan por `@`), puedes aplicar el `SET ...` directamente sobre ellas. Puedes leer [esta interesante respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754790/5587982) sobre los tipos de variables en MySQL. Por otra parte, tampoco veo **dónde** usas esas variables (`@`).

Comment: me había olvidado de poner los VALUES en el INSERT, ya está corregido

Answer (score 1):

Cuatro detalles para que soluciones estos problemas:

1.- No es necesario declarar variables.

```
DECLARE @usuario varchar(30), @accion varchar(6), @customer varchar(8)
```

2.- Faltan cerrar algunos delimitadores `;` por T-SQL.

3.- Te falto cerrar el Delimitador del SP al final.

```
DELIMITER ;
```

4.- En MySQL se usan los valores (`NEW.` para insercción y `OLD.` para actualizar o eliminar) para los disparadores; en tu caso deberás usar `NEW`.

```
SET @usuario = (SELECT NEW.Cus_User FROM purchases);
```

Tu código correrá de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON purchases FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET @usuario = (SELECT NEW.Cus_User FROM purchases);
    SET @accion = 'creado';
    SET @customer = (SELECT NEW.Cus_Id FROM purchases);
    INSERT INTO his_cus (HCu_Action, HCu_User, HCu_Cus_Id) VALUES(@accion, @usuario, @customer);
END; $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Me comentas como te fue.